# How to output foreach as a string c# // g prints as an array and not a string

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

```cs
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

foreach (byte e in array)
{
    int v = e + 1;
    char g = (char)v;
    g.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(g);
}
```

The current output is one character on each line, but I want to print only one string.

For instance, if `text` is "hello" then my output should be "ifmmp".

Comment: `g.ToString();` alone is a "no-operation". `ToString()` _returns_ a value, it does not "modify" `g` to turn it into a string. `Console.WriteLine(g.ToString())` would be what you mean. However, I'm not sure it does what you want.

Comment: I tried Console.WriteLine(g.ToString()) but it still prints g as an array

Comment: Can you share the output you are getting and the output you are expecting?

Comment: This question needs work. Its suffering from a lack of specific descriptions of what you want and what is happening (even though you might think you have explained your self, i assure you that you haven't ),

Comment: If my input is "hello" then my output is "ifmmp" which is right but it is on separate line

Comment: @Florin thanks, that's much clearer. I edited your question to add this information directly inside.

Answer (score 1):

I modified you code which prints Ifsf!xf!hp for text "Here we go". Add namespace System.Text to compile the code

```
        byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte e in array)
        {
            int v = e + 1;
            char g = (char)v;
            sb.Append(g);

        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `StringBuilder()` works very efficiently, but the simplest general use-case solution is to just call `Console.Write()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`.

That will cause all string output to be appended on the same line until `Console.WriteLine()` is called or a newline character is otherwise written. It also lets you easily dump content to the terminal for debugging without having to setup additional structure to handle that information flow.

To be super clear, your updated code could be:

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

foreach (byte e in array)
{
    int v = e + 1;
    char g = (char)v;
    g.ToString();
    Console.Write(g);
}

// Optional, resets the carriage to the beginning of the next line
// so that the next output doesn't get appended to the end of the
// same written string.
Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the other function of `Encoding` class, that converts byte array to string.

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
{
    array[index]++;
}
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array));
```